# database is malformed in iphone + error disk i/o error

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I have More than 5000 Record to be loaded from Server to my App and Inserted into Database.
While inserting these records after some successful insertion  I am getting this kind of error and my app crashes.

**database is malformed in iPhone + error disk i/o error**

Following are code snippet that could be useful,Here I am getting Records in 5 Categories One by One and Inserting them into Database

```
    if (tag==1) {
        NSMutableDictionary *catDic=[dic valueForKeyPath:@"GetAllRecords.results.categories.category"];
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(insertDataInCategoryMaster:) withObject:catDic];

        NSMutableDictionary *levelDic=[dic valueForKeyPath:@"GetAllRecords.results.levels.level"];
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(insertDataInLevelMaster:) withObject:levelDic];

        NSMutableDictionary *queDic=[dic valueForKeyPath:@"GetAllRecords.results.questions.question"];

        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(insertDataInQueMaster:) withObject:queDic];

        [self getQueCatLevelData:2];
    }
    else if(tag==2){

        NSMutableDictionary *queDic=[dic valueForKeyPath:@"GetAllRecords.results.questions.question"];
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(insertDataInQueMaster:) withObject:queDic];

        [self getQueCatLevelData:3];

    }
    else if(tag==3){

        NSMutableDictionary *queDic=[dic valueForKeyPath:@"GetAllRecords.results.questions.question"];
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(insertDataInQueMaster:) withObject:queDic];

        [self getQueCatLevelData:4];
    }//and so on for 5 also
```

in each insertDataInQueMaster I am doing  following things.

```
         NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
        for(NSDictionary *queDictionary in dictionary)
        {

            NSString *strQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into QuestionMaster values(%d,'%@','%@',%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,0,'%@')",[[queDictionary valueForKey:@"questionid"]intValue], [queDictionary valueForKey:@"questiontext"],[queDictionary valueForKey:@"answertext"],[[queDictionary valueForKey:@"categoryid"]intValue],[[queDictionary valueForKey:@"levelid"] intValue],[[queDictionary valueForKey:@"status"]intValue],[[queDictionary valueForKey:@"RangeFrom"]intValue],[[queDictionary valueForKey:@"RangeTo"]intValue],[queDictionary valueForKey:@"Fact"]];

            [NSNumber requestWithSynchronousExcuteQuery:strQuery withReturnningError:&error];

            if(error)
            {
                NSLog(@"error description:%@",[[error userInfo] description]);
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:NO forKey:@"FirstTime"];
            }

        }

        count++;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:count forKey:@"CheckCount"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        [pool drain];
```

I am doing These all things while App is Loading in AppDelegate.m , that too in Background
The Error Comes After  successfully inserting few records in Database so I think there is no problem with Database opening and Inserting.

I hope I am clear,
Please comment if any confusion.
Waiting for reply.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're doing something to corrupt the SQLite file.  Could be accessing it from two different threads without locking (though usually SQLite is compiled to protect itself from this), could be some other file operation you're doing (such as accidentally falling down the path that reinitializes your DB).

Comment: (Keep in mind that if you use SQLite in multiple threads you *must* somehow serialize/lock accesses to the DB to prevent conflicts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hurray, I got the Simple Solution to this

I just Placed

```
  @synchronized(self)
  {
      //My Whole Code  for Background methods goes here
  }
```

and that's it, it solved my error and crash too.

The @synchronized()directive locks a section of code for use by a single thread. Other threads are blocked until the thread exits the protected code—that is, when execution continues past the last statement in the @synchronized() block.

The @synchronized() directive takes as its only argument any Objective-C object, including self.

Comment: You just have to make sure that the *same* `self` is being used in *all* the locations where you do DB operations.  And also make sure you cover the *entire* operation in one synchronized range, from the first `select` to `finalize`.